# How to create blank space to replace white in a code

Tags: html, widget, tumblr

Being a relatively new user of flash, I might not use the right "terms" and thus end up confusing you. For that, I apologize in advance. Anyway, I am trying to use this:

http://abowman.com/google-modules/stingray/?edit=true

Widget, as its maker calls it. What I am trying to do is make the background an unspecific amount of blank space - so the the stingray would float over my webpage without obstructing its content. I thought of 2 methods, both of which didn't work;

1. Change the background image to a large empty .png, and
2. Simply remove everything that looked background related in the code.

Despite my best, and rather pitiful, efforts, I can get nothing but a big ugly square of white. Any ideas? Oh, here's my code by the way:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" style="outline:none;" data="http://stingraygadget.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/stingray.swf?up_stingrayColor=000000&up_backgroundImage=&up_backgroundColor=FFFFFF&up_stingrayName=Stingray&up_speed=.2&" width="300" height="200">
    <param name="movie" value="http://stingraygadget.googlecode.com/svn/ trunk/stingray.swf?up_stingrayColor=000000&up_backgroundImage=http://i.imgur.com/0Id3HHg.png&up_backgroundColor=FFFFFF&up_stingrayName=Stingray&up_speed=.2&"></param>

    <param name="AllowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>

    <param name="wmode" value="opaque"></param>

    <param name="scale" value="noscale"/>

    <param name="salign" value="tl"/>
</object>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background of a flash to tranparent if you wish.

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
```

However this is not supported in all browsers AND I'm not sure if you can do this without saving the `.swf`-file as a file with transparent background (you should have made it yourself to do this (?))

FYI: [isflashdeadyet.com](http://isflashdeadyet.com/)